# Is it possible to explicitly ask Phantom JS to use IPv6 address

Tags: dns, phantomjs, ipv6, ipv4

I want to know if there is any way to instruct PhantomJS to explicitly use IPv6 address for a domain.

I tried specifying the IPv6 address directly (https://[2001:4860:4860::8888]/) and its working fine.

But I want to specify just https://www.google.com and want the PhantomJS to use IPv6 address instead of IPv4 address.
Is it possible to do it?

Thanks in advance.